# mod_rewrite installed but not working

Tags: apache

```
    <?php info(); ?>
```

shows “mod_rewrite” under “enabled modules”.

Here is my /var/www/.htaccess:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options +Index
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^foo.html$ index.html
    RewriteLog “rw.log”## Heading ##
```

/var/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
    <Directory "/var/www"> 
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews Includes
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

/var/www :

```
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  111 2011-10-31 21:09 .htaccess
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  197 2011-10-31 21:01 index.html
```

Yet instead of redirecting me to the index page, http://localhost/foo.html just gives me a 404. The rewrite log hasn’t been created, and the apache error log doesn’t record anything besides a 404. What am I doing wrong? I’ve spent hours reading through various tutorials and the apache documentation, and I’m thoroughly bamboozled. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a quick trial on my server, your lines in .htaccess were giving errors for me:
+Index (Should be +Indexes)
RewriteLog “rw.log”## Heading ## (Apache reported that it wasn't allowed here).

Try changing to +Indexes and removing RewriteLog for now, then see what the last errors were in the apache log.

Comment: +Index => +Indexes and RewriteLog removed.  Unfortunately /var/log/apache2/error.log still only shows that it can't find "foo.html" and that it's restarting when I've told it to.

Comment: It's restarting the entire server when it can't find foo.html? Maybe paste the error message in here.

Comment: Oh no, I mean I'm restarting apache every so often just in case that helps.  I don't think it's anything irregular:[Mon Oct 31 22:43:25 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/foo.html' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Oct 31 22:43:25 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/foo.html' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Oct 31 22:43:47 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Oct 31 22:43:48 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: [Mon Oct 31 22:43:48 2011] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Mon Oct 31 22:43:48 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Oct 31 22:43:50 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/foo.html' not found or unable to stat

Comment: If you Apache config didn't detect the errors in the .htaccess then it's clearly not being read. You could try entering some garbage in there or doing -Indexes (with removing index.html) to see why it's not reading it.